# Exception in thread “main” java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 error in my Java program

Tags: arrays, loops

I made this sample program for a while, and I'm figuring out how to add the sum of the two employees' pay I inputted in the array. Any suggestions?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Sample {
public static void main (String[] args)

{
    String Name;
    int i, HoursWorked, Rate, Pay=0, TotalPay=0, GrandTotalPay=0;
    int CivStatus=0, Single=500, Married=1000;

    System.out.println("Name\t\t\t\tCivil Status Code\t\t\tPay");

    int [] Employees = new int [2];
    for (i=0; i<Employees.length; i++)
    {
        Name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name: ");
        HoursWorked=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter hours worked: "));
        Rate=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter hourly rate: "));
        Pay=HoursWorked*Rate;
        CivStatus=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your civil status: \nEnter [1] if single.\nEnter [2] if married."));

        if(CivStatus==1){
            {
                TotalPay=Pay-Single;
            } 
        }
        if(CivStatus==2){
            {
                TotalPay=Pay-Married;
            }
        }
        GrandTotalPay=Employees[0]+Employees[1];
        System.out.println(Name+"\t\t\t\t"+CivStatus+"\t\t\t\t\t"+Pay);
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of the pay is: "+GrandTotalPay);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Array index Out of bounds exception occurs when you try to access a memory location not present in the array.
You are doing same in

```
for (i=0; i<=Employees.length; i++)
```

Instead, do

```
for (i=0; i<Employees.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

After you calculate each Pay, add it to TotalPay.
Like:

```
TotalPay = TotalPay + Pay;
```

Or,

```
TotalPay += Pay;
```

The next thing, you actually are not using the array here. If you want to keep the Pays in the array, you need an array of size 2.

```
int[] Employees = new int[2];
```

Another thing, when traversing an array, do it like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < Employees.Length; i++) {}
```

Array indexing starts from 0, and goes up to (size - 1), so you cannot use <= Employees.Length here.

Answer (score 0):

Array index starts from 0. If you want to loop through all elements use indices from 0 till length. 
**Change `i<=Employees.Length` into `i<Employees.Length`**

Comment: Thanks! I did as you asked, but how will I be able to add the sum of the two employees' pay?

Comment: In which data structure you having the pay details. Array right? then add another loop for adding the pay

Comment: @BrianIrvin accept the answer if its working. for further assistance update question with the code you've right now for adding the pay details.

Comment: I have updated the code I posted. I'm still lost on finding the sum of the two arrays. What do I put? :(

Comment: Adding arrays a[length] and b[length]                                    for(i=0;i<length;i++)  {                                                                      sum=a[i]+b[i]                                                                                                     } change array names as you having.

Comment: Did as you told me. But I always get zero as the sum. :(

Comment: @BrianIrvin Please check the answer, it meets your need.

Comment: Hey, I'm getting an error with 'Pay' it has red underlines. :( What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below and make changes. Note: changed `Pay` into an Array for holding pay of each employees

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Sample {
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String Name;
    int i, HoursWorked, Rate, TotalPay=0, GrandTotalPay=0;
    int CivStatus=0, Single=500, Married=1000;

System.out.println("Name\t\t\t\tCivil Status Code\t\t\tPay");
int [] Pay = new int [2];
int [] Employees = new int [2];
for (i=0; i<Employees.length; i++)
{
    Name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name: ");
    HoursWorked=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter hours worked: "));
    Rate=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter hourly rate: "));
    Pay[i]=HoursWorked*Rate;
    CivStatus=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your civil status: \nEnter [1] if single.\nEnter [2] if married."));

    if(CivStatus==1){
        {
            TotalPay=Pay[i]-Single;
        } 
    }
    if(CivStatus==2){
        {
            TotalPay=Pay[i]-Married;
        }
    }
    GrandTotalPay+=Pay[i];
    System.out.println(Name+"\t\t\t\t"+CivStatus+"\t\t\t\t\t"+Pay[i]);
}
System.out.println("The sum of the pay is: "+GrandTotalPay);
    }
}
```

Thanks.